# Flutter Web Apple Sign in Pop Up immediately closes

Tags: flutter

I have been struggling with Apple Sign in for Futter Web. I finally got it working or so I thought. When I click my logging button for apple in my flutter web up in the emulator I get a nice pop up asking me to sign into the app.

So I pushed the code to my website, and when I click the same login button in production the pop up opens and immediatley closes. I have tried in both chrome and Safari and I get the same result.

All I am running to log in, is this code when the login button is pressed:

```
final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPopup(appleProvider);
  } else {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error message on the console? If so, provide it as well pls

Comment: Not getting any error because the pop up stays open in the chrome emulator. Not sure how to read any error in production once its pushed to firebase hosting @MinjinGelegdorj

Comment: Try running your code in debug mode and look at the console message. There must be a hint.